# Automatically insert new record into child table when new record is added to parent table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have a one to many relationship between a IdeaLog table and a IdeaStatus table respectively. I am trying to create an application using lightswitch and C# to allow a user to enter new idea into the IdeaLog table. Once that record is created I want it to be created in the IdeaStatus table with a default status of submitted. So far I haven't been able to find any information online to help me do this. Any nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should check out triggers in the database that you're using.

Comment: However please notice that if you're about to use ORM, it will get crazy not knowing what's going on when trigger fires and creates new record that is not tracked by EntityFramework proxy.

Answer (score 1):

In your Lightswitch Server project:

1. Locate your Data Sources.
2. Locate the parent table (.lsml) and open it.
3. Up the top locate "Write Code" and click the drop down arrow on the right.
4. Select the appropriate event. e.g. IdeaLog_Inserted
5. Insert a record into the IdeaStatus table using EntityFramework (or SQL, etc)